# Getting all Kubernetes pods that start with a prefix

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a Kubernetes cluster with several (unknown number, as more can be created at run time) pods with have a label prefix of `x=y`. Based on this prefix (`x=`), how can I programmatically get a list of all the `y` values?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like bellow:

```golang
# kClient ---> Kubernetes Client

# List all the pods from all namespaces
podList, err := es.kClient.CoreV1().Pods(core.NamespaceAll).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

# Store answer in Ys
var Ys []string

# Loop over all the pods, and check for the label key "x"
# If "x" exists, store the value of "y" in Ys.
for _, pod := range podList.Items {
    if y, exists := pod.Labels["x"]; exists {
        Ys = append(Ys, y)
    }
}


fmt.Println(Ys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use kubernetes client coreV1Api to list the pods matching the labels.

```
coreV1Api.list_namespaced_pod(namespace=<namespace>, label_selector="X=Y")
```